# It it possible to avoid kiwi.com's automatic online check-in and instead do it manually by yourself?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, fees-and-charges, seating

I have a WestJet Flight LGW-YYC that I booked using kiwi.com. WestJet offers free seat selection with the online check-in on their homepage (see their [FAQ](https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/contact-us/faqs/seat-selection) at "
Can I still select my seat if I don't want to pay the fee?").

With the automatic online check-in that kiwi.com provides by default, I can not select the seat for free during check-in, instead I have to pay a 30€ fee.

Can I avoid the automatic check-in by kiwi.com, do the check-in manually by myself on the WestJet homepage, and in this way select my seat for free?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I found it wasn't covered by the kiwi.com FAQ so I called kiwi.com customer service, and after some confusion and explaining they disabled the automatic check-in for my flight.

Comment: Is this something that you can do in their website or something that you *have* to contact Kiwi to do on the back end?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I searched the kiwi.com website extensively for this option, but didn't find it. Also the lady I talked to was quite surprised by my request at first and had to ask her superior for help, so I guess you have to directly contact them at the moment. But as after the talk to her boss she explicitely thanked me for pointing out this issue they didn't know about, it might be something they'll implement in the future.

Comment: I wonder what would've happened if you just went ahead and checked in yourself without calling Kiwi

Comment: @JonathanReez Definitely a valid question, but I honestly don't wanna be the one to test it :)

Comment: I also wonder if changing your seats once checked in is also an option: kiwi sends you the boarding pass then you can over to westjet yourself and change seats?